# Smoothing artifacts on wheel spokes

Tags: modeling, mesh, topology, subdivision-surface

I'm modelling a wheel and I can't get rid of these overhang artifacts where the spokes meet the inside of the wheel. I've spent 3+ hours trying to fix it to no avail. There has to be a way to do this. [image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Adding loop cuts to get rid of the N-gons fixes the issue,  but also ruins the shape of the wheel.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get rid of those n-gons.
For that, you'll need way more *evenly spaced* edges to support the geometry.

1. Add more edges using *Loopcuts*. It will deform the geometry, but don't worry.
2. Select the individual circles, one by one.
3. Use *Mesh > Transform > To sphere* on each circle to smoothen it

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you share your mesh, We can check the topology and make some tests directly on the file.

In general try to:

- use planar faces
- do not use triangle or N-gons

Try to cut on the red line (and remove the edge that generates 3-gons) and add some loop on the yellow lines (it's not 100% clear to me where is problem of your mesh).

[image]